# PHP MVC SQL Syntax error

Tags: php

I am trying to implement a delete function in my MVC site. I have the following error

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'id=27' at line 1
```

At the moment while I am trying to fix the error I have hard coded in the id `27`, I have looked through the syntax for a simple row delete everywhere (eg. http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_delete.asp) but cant seem to find why I am getting the error?

**deleteItem function**

```
        function deleteItem($parameters) {
        $id = '27';

        if ($this->model->deleteItem( $id )) {
            $this->model->hasDeleteFailed = false;
            $this->model->setDeleteItemConfirmation();
            return (true);
        }
        else
            $this->model->deleteItemError ( DELETE_ITEM_ERROR_STR );
    }
```

**SQL Code**

```
    public function deleteItem($id) {
    $delId = $id;
    $sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM items";
    $sqlQuery .= "WHERE id=$delId;";

    $result = $this->getDbManager () -> executeQuery ( $sqlQuery );
}
```

Comment: Could you specify where please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This:

```
$sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM items";
$sqlQuery .= "WHERE id=$delId;";
```

Should be:

```
$sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM items "; // note the extra space at the end
$sqlQuery .= "WHERE id=$delId;";
```

Or:

```
$sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM items";
$sqlQuery .= " WHERE id=$delId;"; // note the extra space at the beggining
```

Comment: Thank you so much! Have been tearing my hair out for days with this error! Always the little things!

Comment: No problem. Feel free to accept the answer if it suited your requirements. Take the habit of **always** `var_dump`ing your `SQL` statements in case of syntax error.

Answer (score 2):

The code

```
$sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM items";
$sqlQuery .= "WHERE id=$delId;";
```

is the problem, since your SQL statement pretty much amounts to:

```
DELETE FROM itemsWHERE id=$delId
```

Notice that there is no space between the word "items" and the word "WHERE" in the SQL statement.

Also, you might as well refactor your code to

```
$sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM items WHERE id=$delId";
```

since there is no benefit to creating the SQL statement over two strings.

Also, you NEED to properly escape your SQL input parameters to prevent [SQL Injection attacks](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). I don't know which PHP Framework you're using, so you'll need to look at how the framework does it. Take a look at the [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) function for this.

Also, you need to validate that the $id variable is actually an integer to prevent SQL Injection, since mysqli_real_escape_string is not entirely safe on its own. Use [intval](http://php.net/manual/en/function.intval.php) for this.

In your case you only need to make sure that $id is an integer value.
Thus, you should change your code to something like:

```
public function deleteItem($id) {
    $delId = intval($id);

    if ($delId <= 0)
        return /* fail since ID is invalid */;

    $sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM items WHERE id=$delId;";

    $result = $this->getDbManager () -> executeQuery ( $sqlQuery );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 public function deleteItem($id) {
    $delId = $id;
    $sqlQuery = "DELETE FROM items";
    $sqlQuery .= " WHERE id=$delId;";

    $result = $this->getDbManager () -> executeQuery ( $sqlQuery );
}
```

Use space in $sqlQuery as I mention.